# How to link related files in Finder on OS X

Tags: mac, finder

I am looking for a way to "link" files on OS X, such that viewing a file in Finder will allow you to see the files you have linked to it. These files are linked only in the sense that they have some sort of relation to each other such that I can easily go to the related file from either of them.

I do not require advanced functionality, such as the ability to programmatically link files or automatically update links when a file moves, although that would be nice. Simply the ability to manually create these "links" would be enough.

Specifically, my use case is that I take pictures and record audio. I organize pictures and audio in separate folders, but sometimes there is a picture and an audio recording of the same thing, and I'd like to be able to document that in a way that makes it easy to go to the files from each other.

Comment: What would these "links" do, exactly?  What do you mean by "go to the files from each other"?  Sounds more like you need media management software which is designed with features such as this.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with Finder. But I have to ask the obvious question: why not store photos and audio that are related in one folder?

Comment: You can definitely use Finder’s Tags to define the relationships. I don’t use them much so I can’t be sure if you can click on one and “follow” it to the rest of the files with the same tag. But you can create a smart search folder that shows all files with that Tag.